# Access parent local variable in child window

Tags: javascript, php, global-variables, parent-child

I would like to use a local variable of a parent in child window. I used `parent.window.opener` but it returns `undefined`.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var selectedVal;

 $(document).ready(function () {
  //....
  //...
   if ($(this).val() == "byActor"){
           $("#tags").focus();
           $("#tags").autocomplete({
             source: "actorsauto.php",
             minLength: 2,
             focus: function( event, ui ){
                   event.preventDefault(); 
                   return false;
             },
             select: function (event, ui){ 
                       var selectedVal = ui.item.value;
                       alert(selectedVal);
                   }
            }); 
   });

$('#btnRight').on('click', function (e) {
         popupCenter("movieByactor.php","_blank","400","400");
});
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and this is a child:

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var selectedVal = parent.window.opener.selectedVal; 
   alert(selectedVal);

 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want both `parent` and `opener`? Also, are you attempting to read `selectedValue` before it is set to a value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't - the whole idea with local variables is that they are only available in whatever function scope they are declared in - and functions inside that function.

In your case select `selectedVal` is only available inside this function declaration:

```
select: function (event, ui){ 
   var selectedVal = ui.item.value;
   alert(selectedVal);
}
```

To use it outside this scope you need to make it global by attaching it to the window:

```
window.selectedVal = 'somevalue';
```

You can also make variables implicitly global by leaving out the `var` keyword - however this is a poor practice and is not allowed in strict mode.

This will allow you to you access `window.selectedVal` by:

```
window.opener.selectedVal // for windows opened with window.open()
window.parent.selectedVal // iframe parent document
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, do you mean that I have to write `window.selectedVal = ui.item.value;` instead of `var selectedVal = ui.item.value;` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete explanation, it worked :)

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var selectedVal = window.opener.selectedVal; 
        alert(selectedVal);

    </script>
</body>
```